# Saving/Loading My.Settings with ListView Control - vb.net

Tags: vb.net, listview, load, save, my.settings

I am making a game in Visual Basic that has to contain a high score table.
I am using a `ListView` control named `lstscores` to store rows of scores in 2 columns called `Name` and `Score`.
The user has to guess words that are entered into a ListBox called `lstwords` when correct.
I have set up 2 things in `Application.Settings`: `settingname` and `settingscore` both with type: `System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollectino`, Scope: `user` and Value: `Nothing`.

When user clicks on a save button, I basically want to take the username and score and store it in the settings respectively. So when I open the form up next time I can load the settings back into the same `ListView` control.

I have been researching for a few hours, and I haven't been able to find anything exactly suited to my needs.

I cannot provide my code, as i have tried everything possible to my knowledge, and nothing has worked.

If someone could please give me advice or a direction on how to go about doing this, I would be very grateful.

Thanks

```
Dim arr(1) As String
    Dim score As Integer

    inputname = txtname.Text
    score = lstwords.Items.Count

    arr(0) = inputname
    arr(1) = score
    lstscores.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(arr))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use combination of `Save()` and `Reload()` methods to store your data. 
When user clicks on Save button, you can iterate your ListView adding content `ListView.Items[n]` to collection of names and content of sub-item (`ListViewItem.SubItems[0]`) to collection of scores. Then, use `My.Settings.Save()` to save your data. To have your data back in `ListView` after start, use `My.Settings.Reload()` (in for example `Form.Load` event) and iterate it back. Here's an example of saving iteration (not tested):

```
For Each it0 in lstscores.Items
    My.Settings.settingname.Add(it0.Text)
    My.Settings.settingscore.Add(it0.SubItems[0].Text)
Next
My.Settings.Save()
```

Comment: ok so i tried your code with only the settingname line, and it doesn't even save that to my.settings

Comment: Didi you use `My.Settings.Save()` ?

Comment: `For Each it0 In lstscores.Items`

                               `My.Settings.settingname.Add(it0.Text)`

        `Next`

        `My.Settings.Save()`

Comment: Ok. Have you tried complete solution with loading? How do you check if are contents of my.settings changed? It should be somewhere in filesystem. VS contents won't change, they're default.

Comment: to check the settings have changed, i double click on `My Project` and go `Settings` and the `settingname` setting still has the default xml code. 

to carry the score to the listview control i use the code that i have put in the original question

Comment: Thats not correct. In Visual Studio there are only default values. `My.Settings.Save()` edits special file located in AppData (not sure how it is on newer systems). You can try to search config file there, or you can simply complete `Form.Load` by adding `My.Settings.Reload()` and set breakpoint there (then you can use Watch to check data in My.Settings).